# What is the independent clause of dependent clause?

Tags: clauses

I want to explain my problems with the following sentences:

> "Even boldly going where few have gone doesn't always lead to radical
>   conclusions. Over the years, researchers have set up
>   weather-monitoring stations in remote areas of Antarctica. According
>   to data from stations on the Ross Ice Shelf -where **almost all
>   those** taking part in Robert Scott's ill-fated South Pole expedition
>   perished sometime between late February and mid-March of 1912 -
>   temperatures as low as those recorded in Scott's journal have been
>   documented only once in the past 15 years."

1) In "*where almost all those* ......", who does *those* refer to?

2) That same clause started with *where*. What place does this dependent clause refer to?

3) What is the independent clause for this dependent clause?

Answer (score 2):

The clause in question:

> ***where*** almost all ***those*** taking part in Robert Scott's ill-fated South Pole expedition perished sometime between late February and mid-March of 1912
>
> **where**: the Ross Ice Shelf
>
> **those**: the people that took part in Robert Scott's ill-fated South Pole expedition

Answer (score 2):

> According to data from stations on the Ross Ice Shelf -where almost
> all those taking part in Robert Scott's ill-fated South Pole
> expedition perished sometime between late February and mid-March of
> 1912 - temperatures as low as those recorded in Scott's journal have
> been documented only once in the past 15 years.

1. In the subordinate clause: *where almost all those taking part in Robert Scott's ill-fated South Pole expedition perished sometime between late February and mid-March of 1912*, *[those](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/that)* is a determiner for a reduced noun phrase: *[people] taking part in Robert Scott's ill-fated South Pole expedition.* The word *people* is not written, but it is clearly implied, which allows *those* to be parsed as a pronoun in that context.
2. *Where* refers back to the location specified immediately before it: *on the Ross Ice Shelf*.
3. The independent clause is at the end of the sentence: ***temperatures** as low as those recorded in Scott's journal **have been documented** only once in the past 15 years*. *Temperatures* is the subject of the passive verbal phrase *have been documented*.

Answer (score 0):

"Where almost all those taking part in Robert Scott's ill-fated South Pole expedition perished sometime between late February and mid-March of 1912" is a (non-restrictive) *relative clause*, introduced by the relative adverb "where", which refers back to the antecedent *The Ross Ice Shelf*.

*Those* is a pronoun. It is often deictic (pointing), but here it serves as the antecedent to the participial phrase *taking part in Robert Scott's ill-fated South Pole expedition*. So on its own it has no designand; but it nominalises the participial phrase, giving the sense "the ones who took part ... "